# Get the URI from the default web proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, proxy

I'm writing a program that should work without proxy and with proxy with authentication - automatically! It should call a WCF service. In this example the instance is called `client`. I also use a self written class (`proxyHelper`) that requests the credentials.

```
 BasicHttpBinding connection = client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;<br/>
 connection.ProxyAddress = _???_<br/>
 connection.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;<br/>
 connection.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;<br/>
 connection.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;<br/>
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = proxyHelper.Username;
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = proxyHelper.Password;
```

I'm facing a problem getting the ProxyAddress. If I use `HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` to get actual defined proxy I see in debug mode the *correct* proxy address but it's a non public property. Setting UseDefaultWebProxy to true doesn't work and if I add the proxy address hard-coded and set the UseDefaultWebProxy to false it works fine. So... how can I gather the address of the default web proxy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proxy has a method called [GetProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.getproxy.aspx) which can be used to get the Uri of the proxy.

Here's a snippet of the description from MSDN:

> The GetProxy method returns the URI
> that the WebRequest instance uses to
> access the Internet resource.
>
> GetProxy compares destination with the
> contents of BypassList, using the
> IsBypassed method. If IsBypassed
> returns true, GetProxy returns
> destination and the WebRequest
> instance does not use the proxy
> server.
>
> If destination is not in BypassList,
> the WebRequest instance uses the proxy
> server and the Address property is
> returned.

You can use the following code to get the proxy details.  Note that the Uri that you pass to the GetProxy method is important, as it will only return you the proxy credentials if the proxy isn't bypassed for the specified Uri.

```
var proxy = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

//gets the proxy uri, will only work if the request needs to go via the proxy 
//(i.e. the requested url isn't in the bypass list, etc)
Uri proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));

Console.WriteLine(proxyUri.Host);
Console.WriteLine(proxyUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot! I just added the line: Uri proxyAddress = proxy.GetProxy(client.Endpoint.Address.Uri);

Comment: I do not have the `.Dump()` method available. What library is that?

Comment: @codeMonkey, sorry, that's my fault.  It's an extension method from [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), it's pretty similar to using `Console.WriteLine(proxyUri.Host)`.  I'd highly recommend trying out [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), it's a good way of being able to run C# snippets without having to write a full application.

Comment: Dump method does not exist. 
AbsoluteUri returns the address of the URI I entered, not of the proxy.

Comment: @DoronSaar, dump is an extension method from LinqPad that dumps the variable to console. I will remove it from the example and replace with Console.Write. As I stated in my answer, the Uri returned will only be the proxy Uri if it needs to go through the proxy. If it doesn't need to go through the proxy, it will just return the Uri you entered. Reasons for this can be that you don't have a proxy set on the host machine, or the Uri is in the proxy bypass list.

Comment: @downvoter, would you care to add a comment as to why you've downvoted this answer? I'd like to improve it if you've found a problem with it.