# Using WebClient in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, proxy, webclient

I am using WebClient to download some resource in following way:

```
 Stream stream;
 try
 {
  WebClient webClient = new webClient();
  stream = webClient.OpenRead(MyResourceUri);
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
  return null;
 }
 return stream;
```

When I do this in a WPF application, it works fine and proper stream is obtained.

When I do this in a WCF service call, it doesn't work. A WebException is thrown with message `"Unable to connect to remote server"`. (It works for files hosted on my machine or within company network, however it fails for any resource on web). The service is hosted on IIS7.

Investigation so far reveals the difference is because of the webproxy. The webclient.proxy in WPF application refers to the proxy settings as set in IE, whereas the one in WCF is having none.

Why is it so? And more importantly, how can I make the WebClient in WCF use similar proxy settings?

EDIT: I set the proxy on WebClient and it worked in WCF service

```
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyAddressFromIE);
```

Here I have hardcoded the proxy addess. What method/APIs are there to obtain one? And still why its different in WCF service & in WPF application?

Comment: What type of resources are you trying to request using WebClient?

Comment: Its just PNGs (Getting generated through the query string in URL).

Comment: Are you trying to deliver the PNGs as an encoded image? Or can you simply pass the URI to the client and have it render the image?

Comment: No, I can't pass the URI. I didn't want to go into details of this, thats why I mentioned <resources> as it would distract from the actual problem which is calling WebClient's methods in WCF service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer one of your questions, the reason there is a difference between your WPF application and your IIS hosted WCF service is this.

WPF applications run in an actual Windows session (your user session to be exact). This means there is a user profile loaded for that session and that session contains, amongst other things, the proxy settings as configured in IE.

WCF services hosted in IIS do not run in a Windows session. They are run as a service and therefor do not have a Windows session (they actually run in session 0, but that's just an implementatio detail). This means there is no proxy configuration.

To reliably solve this, you could have your own configuration for a proxy, perhaps in web.config.
Another option is to configure the proxy through netsh.exe.

Comment: For obtaining proxy, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844467/c-sharp-auto-detect-proxy-settings. For the different behavior in WPF app & WCF service, your explaination seems reasonable, so accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the exact same thing, and I found the answer here: [Get the URI from the default web proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254351/get-the-uri-from-the-default-web-proxy).  Basically, you need to dynamically read the proxy using `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` and by determining the proxy using a test proxied url.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Consider handling the call using sources other than the highly abstracted WebClient. From the higher to lower level, this means exploring WebRequest and WebResponse objects all the way down to programming off the socket. The reason is the WebClient method is tightly coupled to choices in Internet Explorer, as much of the high level Internet stack is in windows. If you want to get around this, you need to dig deeper.

I would love to point a finger at precisely where to dig, but I have not incurred this particular issue and have no experience solving. I know where to look for the answer, but no specifics on "X marks the spot". Because of the high level, highly abstracted nature of WebClient, however, I am not sure you can easily get around the implicit creation of the stack and/or the coupling with IE, without more headaches than punting and using an object that gives more explicit control of HTTP communication.

Happy hunting.